# Computer doesn't recognize hard drive for booting windows 8

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning

I've been trying to install Ubuntu on my computer today to dual boot with Windows 8.1. I created a 10 gigabyte partition for Ubuntu and then tried to install it. During the installation process, I selected something else. I set aside 1 gigabyte for the swap area and the remaining 9 gigabytes as the Ext4 mounted on /. Then when I clicked install, it would go to the next page but then a popup message appeared with only question marks and then it went back to the page where it asks how I would like to install Ubuntu.

At this point, I tried it a few more times and then I decided to give up and come back at another time and so I clicked the restart button in Ubuntu. Now, whenever my computer boots, it says that there are no bootable devices recognized by the computer. It will only boot when I have the USB with Ubuntu on it plugged in. I checked the boot-priority list in my BIOS and it lists HDD0 as first but it doesn't boot to Windows when I start my computer.  I will try boot-repair now but I just wanted to get this question out there in case it doesn't work.

I guess I kind of have two questions. The first is how would I get my computer to recognize and boot to the Windows partition. The second would be if I proceeded to attempt to dual boot with Ubuntu, what steps should I take?

This is my first time working with anything Linux related and any help would be greatly appreciated. This is my only computer and I need it for work. Thanks in advance!

UPDATE
Here's the link to the results of my Boot-Repair
http://paste.ubuntu.com/8003085/

Comment: What is the status of your system after running boot-repair?

Answer (score 0):

1)you have to use a GNU parted disk as util fdisk doesnt support GPT

if this doesnt fix it then,

2)you have to re-install the hard disk, most hard-disks self install themselves but when you tried to install Ubuntu you could have deleted these drivers. you can search Google on how to do this.

3)secondly your hard disk could be loose and thus cant communicate with a computer.

4)last of all this could be because you wrote Ubuntu over windows and now windows cant read the hard disk.